# Is ALLAH(swt) formless and bodyless.?

Tags: quran, allah

> "And there is none comparable to Him."
> Surah Ikhlas

Can this verse be interpret as ALLAH can not even be compared with something formless?

Like Energy or plasma?

Answer (score 1):

Allah has a form because the people in Jannah will be able to see him and that is indeed the greatest reward.

- *Then the Owner of Majesty and Honour will appear and say: ‘Ask of Me.’ They will say: ‘We ask for Your good pleasure, O Lord.’ He will say: ‘It is because I am pleased with you that you are in My Paradise, and you are honoured.’ Then He will say (again): ‘Ask of Me.’ They will say all together: ‘We ask for Your good pleasure.’ He will ask them to testify that He is pleased with them. Then He will say (once more): ‘Ask of Me,’ and they will ask of Him until each one of them is finished. Then He will grant them that which no eye has seen, no ear has heard, and it has not crossed the mind of any human.”*

At-Tabaraani narrated in al-Mu‘jam al-Kabeer (6717)

- *It is narrated from Abu Hurayrah that some people said: “O Messenger of Allaah, will we see our Lord on the Day of Resurrection?” The Messenger of Allaah said, “Do you doubt that you see the moon on the night when it is full?” They said, “No, O Messenger of Allaah.” He said, ‘Do you doubt that you see the sun when there is no cloud?” They said, “No, O Messenger of Allaah.” He said, “You will see Him likewise…”*

Al-Bukhaari (6088) and Muslim (267)

Answer (score 0):

Allah is beyond our capability to imagine.

"Say he is Allah - he's singular,
Allah is unexpendable,
he didn't give birth nor was he born,
and comparable to him is no one." Al-Ikhlas (purity).

Cannot be compared to anything.

Although there is "al-mathal al-a'la", when you for example explain something about Allah by means of something else but you are not comparing, only explaining. You should read a book about Allah's names and attributes, like this one: [https://www.amazon.com/Beautiful-Attributes-Important-Principles-Remember/dp/6035000789](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/6035000789)

Allah is Mighty and Wise.

Answer (score 0):

Hands and foot of Allah mentioned in Quran or Hadith are metaphorical. We can't take the meaning literally. There's nothing like Allah [Surah Ikhlas]. He's not like any creations. He's beyond our comprehension.

Answer (score -3):

No, according to Quran:

- he has eyes:
  But construct an Ark under Our eyes and Our inspiration 11:37
  I lavished My Love on you, and to be formed in My Sight. 20:39
  for surely you are before Our eyes 52:48
- a foot:
  hadith saheeh:
  Muhammad said: “Hell will keep saying, ‘Are there any more (to come)?’ until the Lord of Glory, may He be blessed and exalted, places His foot on it, then it will say, ‘Enough, enough, by Your glory!’ And all its parts will be integrated together."
- hands:
  Allah asked, “O Iblîs! What prevented you from prostrating to what I created with My Own Hands? Did you ˹just˺ become proud? Or have you always been arrogant?” 38:75
  They have not shown Allah His proper reverence—when on the Day of Judgment the ˹whole˺ earth will be in His Grip, and the heavens will be rolled up in His Right Hand. Glorified and Exalted is He above what they associate ˹with Him˺!  39:67

Surely Allah knows best.